# Using same object instance from more than one different Backbone/Require views

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I try to write two views login view and register view each renders with same data which is collected from a keyup dom event in both views. Login template has less data field, so less template variables, than register template does.

So I thought of using one model for gui render of those two, forms data model. I am trying to separate the concerns and keep single responsibility for my modules. Now, it is needed to make forms data model a dependency of one view and create in this view, and mention this same instance from the other by making the former view a dependency of this other view. Yet this last should use the same instance of the view it has as a dependency. It seems having only one view and three separate models forms data, login and register and two different templates can be a solution.

This seems surprising. In object orientated paradigm it feels adding a little feature makes its very fast cumbersome, which conflicts with the object orientation ideas. All this feature is for when user clicks register button in the login view the register view render with the just entered data and vice versa.

Is that usage, referencing one view/model from another one for using its models etc., is a wrong use of the Backbone or Require while they are meant to utilise good developing practices such as separation of concerns, single responsibility, and modularisation separation, or that is not bad at all regarding those good dev practices?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit?  You say "Is that a wrong use of the Backbone or Require, or that is not bad ...", but it's not clear to me what you mean by "that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's "wrong" per say to have `View1` depend on `View2` so that `View1` can access a `Model` that `View2` creates ... but I do think it's sub-optimal.  I can think of two other strategies you might want to consider that would let you avoid making `View1` depend on `View2`.

First, you could opt not to *create* the `Model` in `View2`, and instead just *populate* it in `View2` ... and *create* it beforehand in its own module.  In other words:

```
// theLoginData.js
define(['LoginData'], function(LoginData) {
    return new LoginData();
});

// View #2
define(['theLoginData'], function(theLoginData) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        someMethod: function() {
            theLoginData.set(whatever);
        }
    });
});

 // View #1
define(['theLoginData'], function(theLoginData) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        someOtherMethod: function() {
            var whatever = theLoginData.get('whatever');
        }
    });
});
```

The other option would be to still create the `Model` in View2, but "register" it at a more global scope (eg. as a static property on the `Model` class you use for your login data `Model`):

```
// LoginData.js (ie. the Model class for your login data)
define([], function() {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({}, {
        currentLoginData: null
    });
});


// View #2
define(['LoginData'], function(LoginData) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        someMethod: function() {
            LoginData.currentLoginData = new LoginData(whatever);
        }
    });
});

 // View #1
define(['LoginData'], function(LoginData) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        someOtherMethod: function() {
            var whatever = LoginData.currentLoginData.get('whatever');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I will try to understand and adapt the first solution you offer. But for now let me tell what I understand. Because the module `yourModel` does instantiate itself in itself this instance is accessible from both views if I hand them in this module, hence the instance of it, as their dependancy. So I can have what I ask for; same instance of a model from different views.

Comment: Correct.  The `Model` gets created at *load* time, and your `View`s will only reference it at *run* time (ie. they refer to it from inside the `View`'s methods, not at the top-level directly in the module), so they can be guaranteed to always have that `Model` available to them.

Comment: You mean, that instance of the `Model` available to them.